# Cucumber.yml was found, but can't be parsed for Parallel_Tests

Tags: ruby, cucumber, parallel-testing

When running multiple features with the Ruby gem Parallel_Tests in cucumber using this command:

```
parallel_cucumber features/
```

with a cucumber.yml file under my project root>config folder, which looks like:

```
default: --format html --out report<%= ENV['TEST_ENV_NUMBER'] %>.html
```

I receive the following error message:

```
cucumber.yml was found, but could not be parsed. Please refer to cucumber's documentation on correct profile usage.
```

I have looked into this and some others have thought it was due to a rerun.txt file, but i have not created this file and a project file search returns nothing. I am currently at a loss of what is causing cucumber to fail reading in the yaml file. Any help would be great.

As described by another post, I went into lib/
cucumber/cli/profile_loader.rb and added a STDERR output like so:

```
begin
  @cucumber_yml = YAML::load(@cucumber_erb)
rescue StandardError => e
  STDERR.puts @cucumber_erb
  raise(YmlLoadError,"cucumber.yml was found, but could not be parsed.     Please refer to cucumber's documentation on correct profile usage.\n")
end
```

Here is the result:

```
#parallel_reports: --format html --out reports/cukes_.html 
cucumber.yml was found, but could not be parsed. Please refer to cucumber's documentation on correct profile usage.
#      

default: --format htm#l  
-   
oduetf aruelpto:r t-2-.fhotrmmla  #hptamrla l-l-eolu_tr erpeoprotrst:4 .-h-tfmolr a#tp ahrtamlll e-l-_oruetp orretpso:r t-s-/fcourkmeast_ .hhttmmll - ouctu cruempboerrt.sy/mclu kweass_ .fhotumnld, buctu ccuomubledr .nyomtl  bwea sp afrosuendd.,  Pblueta sceo urledf enro tt ob ec upcaurmsbeedr.' sP ldeoacsuem ernetfaetri otno  ocnu ccuomrbreerc'ts  pdroocfuimleen tu astaigoen. 
n correct profile usage.
```

Comment: I deleted cucumber.yml from ...Project\config folder and it solved the problem, now I can run tests again.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this problem and only found solutions that suggested removing `rerun.txt`. That was not an option for me because I rely on that file to rerun failing scenarios.

For some reason Cucumber outputs failing scenarios separated by `\n` in `rerun.txt` which is not accepted by the default command found in `cucumber.yml`.

My solution was to change the first line of `cucumber.yml` to substitute `\n` with a space:

```
rerun = File.file?('rerun.txt') ? IO.read('rerun.txt').gsub(/\n/, ' ') : ""
```

Comment: I forgot to add the rerun flag(s) this time around and was manually copying the output from the tool to add to a rerun file and missed this detail for a later trial.  Nice addition!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the tests of Rails-Cucumber itself. In my case, just running this line fixed the problem:

```
rm .cucumber.rerun
```

Caution, sometimes the `rerun` file can have a different name.

Answer (score 0):

There is a suggestion to use gem update –system

Comment: If you decided to answer the question, feel free to explain it. Answer should be self-explanatory & full.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error

`cucumber.yml was found, but could not be parsed with ERB`

meant that I was running my tests from RubyMine, and had set my `Features folder` not to the root of my project, but to a subfolder in the project called `features`.

When I changed this to the root of my project, it worked out fine!